# Removing rows while looping through them

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to remove all rows form a `Range` that have a cell with value `"Totals"` in them. I tried something like this:

```
For Each cell In rng
    If CStr(cell.Value) = "Totals" Then
        cell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next cell
```

The problem is that whenever there are two rows both containing a cell with `"Totals"` only the first row gets removed. How can I solve that?

Comment: Try looping through your rows backwards, from the last to the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a pattern like this:

```
Dim numberOfRows as Integer, rw as Integer, col as Integer

numberOfRows = 100  // You probably want to set this using your `rng` object 
col = 1 // column 'A' (but set for your situation)

For rw = numberOfRows to 1 Step -1
    If CStr(Cells(rw, col)) = "Totals" Then
        Cells(rw, col).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next rw
```

**EDIT Two alternative methods**

Suppose I have data in `A1:C3` as follows:

```
     A    B        C
1    1    2        3
2    4    Totals   5
3    6    7        8
```

I want to delete any rows containing `Totals`. Here are two ways to do it:

```
Sub MarkToDelete()
    Dim rng As Range, cl As Range, rw As Integer

    Set rng = Range("A1:C3")

    For Each cl In rng
        If cl = "Totals" Then
            Cells(cl.Row, 4) = "DELETE" //i.e. in column D add a note to delete
        End If
    Next cl

    For rw = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(rw, 4) = "DELETE" Then
            Cells(rw, 4).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next rw
End Sub

Sub LoopRemove()
    Dim rw As Integer, col As Integer

    Set rng = Range("A1:C3")

    For rw = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        For col = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            If Cells(rw, col) = "Totals" Then
                Cells(rw, col).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next col
    Next rw
End Sub
```

Comment: `Next cell` What is this supposed to do?

Comment: It should be `rw`. Updated it now.

Comment: The problem is that now it doesn't loop through all columns. Do you know how to fix that (so it doesn't break when a row is removed)?

Comment: Two options: (1) For each row add another step to loop over columns, or (2) Go with your original method, mark a column as 'DELETE' and then use my method to actually remove the rows.

Comment: The first option works great, thought it's gonna break it. Thanks!